# Cross Domain REST POST Does Preflight Check But No Follow Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, rest, cors

I'm new to web programming so bear with me.  I've created a simple REST API in python flask, and am hosting it with Apache 2.4.  I've tested it via cURL and it works.  Now I'm trying to access it via a web interface with jQuery.

The REST api is at http://api.localhost and the website that accesses it is at http://localhost.

The code I'm using to try and do a POST looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://api.localhost/auth',
        data: '{"username":"user1", "password":"abcxyz"}',
        success: function(data) { console.log(data); alert('data: ' + data);  },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

However, it seems the success function doesn't run.  Looking in dev console (f12) I can see that instead of a POST to that URL, and OPTIONS HTTP request is made.  My understanding is this is a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) preflight check, to make sure it's OK for localhost to access api.localhost.

I've added the following lines to my apache config for api.localhost:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
```

It seems to be working to because the OPTIONS request returns a 200 (and no other data).  However, there is no follow up.  My understanding is since the server is saying it's OK for anyone to POST to api.localhost, that it should go ahead and do the POST next, but it doesn't.

Here are the preflight check request headers:

```
Host: api.localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101
Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Here are the response headers for that same request (remember, status 200):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 07 Dec 2017 00:17:08 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Debian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

You can see that the server is saying any domain is fine (*) and that POST is OK.  However, there is no follow up POST.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: try changing `'*'` to `'http://localhost'` and add an error handler to the ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://api.localhost/auth` must also send `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type`.

So to your Apache config, you also need to add this:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type"
```

That’s necessary because the `contentType: "application/json"` part of your frontend code adds a `Content-Type: application/json` header to the request, and any values for the `Content-Type` request header other than `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or `multipart/form-data` will trigger browsers to send a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request.

So if you have your `http://api.localhost/auth` server send back the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type` response header, that should cause the preflight to succeed, and so cause the browser to move on to making the `POST` request from your frontend code.

Comment: It looks like it's doing the preflight for every single request.  That's going to double the number of requests.  Is there any way around that?

Comment: You can make your Apache server also send the Access-Control-Max-Age
 response header, which tells the browser to cache the OPTIONS response, and for how long. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age. But you probably don’t want to set it any higher than 600 (=10 minutes), because if you do, Chrome clamps it to 600 anyway (that is, in Chrome, the OPTIONS response will never get cached for any longer than 10 minutes).

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  Even 5 seconds would be huge.  Let's say that when the page first loads, I request 10 methods.  That's going to generate 20 requests, but with even a 5 second cache, that would knock that down to 11.